# Xcode 4.2 compiling for iOS 3.1.3 Device

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4, compilation

I'm trying to compile my app to a iPhone 3 with iOS 3.1.3. The device is activated as developer and I've configured the deployment target to iOS 3.1 so the iPhone is detected.

When I click Run, it compiles with no error and says "Finished running MyApp on iPhone of myname". However, the app's not executing in the iPhone, nothing happens.

What am I suppose to do to run the app in my old device? When I try with a iPhone 4 there's no problem!

Thanks!

Comment: Check your product's deployment target.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the architectures you are building for in your build settings.  You should have armv6 in there for the iPhone 3.

Comment: Thank You!  Note: in Xcode 4.2 - armv6 wasn't an option for me in the Architectures field. I had to select it, choose "Other...", then use the + sign to manually type in "armv6" NOT IN PLACE OF but IN ADDITION TO what was already entered there, which was "$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)" and then this worked for me.

Comment: Another note... while I got the app to run on my iPod Touch OS 3.1.3 - it did not run as well as I wanted it to (as well as it runs on the iPad and iPhone in OS 5 and OS 4.2) so I ended up NOT supporting armv6 and setting the iOS Deployment Target for my app to iOS 3.2

Answer (score 0):

What I did (for Xcode 4.2 - ymmv with other versions) is go to the target "Build Settings", and under "architectures" select the "Other..." in the pop-up.  Then, type in "armv6 armv7".  This will enable the app to run in both iPhone 1g and above.  Be sure to build with the "Latest iOS" SDK.  That's what allowed me to deploy to both my iPhone 1g and my iPhone 3gs and above. This builds a "fat" binary which can be used for either architecture, and can be built optimized when you deploy as a release.  Basically what ObjectiveFlash noted, but it might not have been clear to other readers (I myself didn't notice until I re-read it).

Comment: Oh yeah, the OpenGL ES 2.0 is currently only available on the arm7 family of devices, if that matters to you...